What is the highest known temperature where micelles exist?
What are the two liquid phases involved in the formation of roughly spherical micelles at highest possible temperatures? What about a surfactant? At how high temperatures have micelles been observed experimentally?
For obvious reasons, mostly micelles are studied in aqueous solutions. I wonder if there are similar phenomena in metallurgy or liquid minerals, for example.
There are many simple binary phase diagrams with wide miscibility gaps in their two-liquid state, at high temperatures. If there was a stable molecule or atom which preferred to stay at the liquid-liquid interface, rather than dissolve in either of the liquids, this would probably act as a surfactant, but I don't know any real examples of this kind.

Would you consider opal formation as micelles? If limited to organic molecules the temperature ranges are pretty limited.

@JonCuster I intended to ask about supramolecular chemistry, as the tag suggests. I may have not found the best words to distinguish molecular micelles and those composed of equidistant atoms (Si-O-Si  linkages in 3 dimensions give only 1 molecule per micelle in opals)

You are trying to generalize or find parallels between systems (say aqueous surfactant solutions and mineral melts). To generalize, the question is what are properties of the system components that maximize the property in question for the types of system of interest?

@BuckThorn True, but also I am open to the possibility that experimental observations have been done without even understanding these properties. This is another way to answer.

How is finding a micellar system with a very high T useful when comparing an aqueous surfactant solution to a melt? Are you considering high pressure systems? Perhaps you can provide more examples or details to help clarify the point of the question.

I do not limit the question to low pressures. My hope is to get a good example as an answer. I wrote 'aqueous solutions' , to give an idea of what kind of well-studied systems am I already familiar with, and an  idea of size range of these microstructures might be similar in other liquids.

@BuckThorn I edited the Q. The point should be clear to any chemist now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Perhaps ionic liquids are a good bridge between the systems.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think they got micelles above 400°C here: https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.ado7088

https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cphc.200500419
